# Why does Flask produce a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET?

Tags: python, ssl, flask

Python code on sever:

```py
from flask import *
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return Response('Index')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='***.***.***.***', port=80, ssl_context=('certificates/cert.pem', 'certificates/key.pem'))
```

the cert.pem and key.pem files have been generated using:

```sh
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

and the tutorial available [here](http://openssl%20req%20-x509%20-newkey%20rsa:4096%20-nodes%20-out%20cert.pem%20-keyout%20key.pem%20-days%20365) and they will be soon updated using certbot.

I also tried to check with `curl` the output using:
`curl -i https://***.***.***.***:80 -k >> CurlOutput.txt`
but the file is empty.

Is there a way to keep the current certificate until certbot's certificate is ready and also to solve the connection problem?

Comment: Can you add the actual error to your answer?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. When I try to reach the server from any browser it produces the error

Answer (score 1):

You're using port 80 to serve SSL. Use port 443 which is destined for HTTPS. Had the same error and this solved it for me.

So simply change the last line to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True, host='***.***.***.***', port=443, ssl_context=('certificates/cert.pem', 'certificates/key.pem'))
```